# Force Hibernate to issue DELETEs prior to INSERTs to avoid unique constraint violations?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, ora-00001, deferrable-constraint

Background: http://jeffkemponoracle.com/2011/03/11/handling-unique-constraint-violations-by-hibernate

Our table is:

```
BOND_PAYMENTS (BOND_PAYMENT_ID, BOND_NUMBER, PAYMENT_ID)
```

There is a Primary key constraint on BOND_PAYMENT_ID, and a Unique constraint on (BOND_NUMBER, PAYMENT_ID).

The application uses Hibernate, and allows a user to view all the Payments linked to a particular Bond; and it allows them to create new links, and delete existing links. Once they’ve made all their desired changes on the page, they hit “Save”, and Hibernate does its magic to run the required SQL on the database. Apparently, Hibernate works out which records need to be deleted, which need to be inserted, and leaves the rest untouched. Unfortunately, it does the INSERTs first, then it does the DELETEs.

If the user deletes a link to a payment, then changes their mind and re-inserts a link to the same payment, Hibernate quite happily tries to insert it then delete it. Since these inserts/deletes are running as separate SQL statements, Oracle validates the constraint immediately on the first insert and issues **ORA-00001 unique constraint violated**.

We know of only two options:

1. Make the constraint deferrable
2. Remove the unique constraint

Option 2 is not very palatable, because the constraint provides excellent protection from nasty application bugs that might allow inconsistent data to be saved. We went with option 1.

```
ALTER TABLE bond_payments ADD
  CONSTRAINT bond_payment_uk UNIQUE (bond_number, payment_id)
  DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

The downside is that the index created to police this constraint is now a non-unique index, so may be somewhat less efficient for queries. We have decided this is not as great a detriment for this particular case. Another downside (advised by Gary) is that it may suffer from a particular Oracle bug - although I believe we will be immune (at least, mostly) due to the way the application works.

Are there any other options we should consider?

Comment: Would you mind providing some code, like: the entities affected, the code between sf.openSession and session.close?

Comment: By the way: Hibernate does inserts before, but only inserts for entities, not for relationships. The insert operation for relationships (collections) is the 5th step :-)

Comment: I'm not a Hibernate coder myself - I'm the Oracle guy - I'll see if the resident Java dev guru can give some details :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the problem you described, it's not clear if you have an entity `BondPayment` or if you have a `Bond` linked directly to a `Payment`. For now, I suppose you have the link between `Payment` and `Bond` through `BondPayment`. In this case, Hibernate is doing the right thing, and you'll need to add some logic in your app to retrieve the link and remove it (or change it). Something like this:

```
bond.getBondPayment().setPayment(newPayment);
```

You are probably doing something like this:

```
BondPayment bondPayment = new BondPayment();
bondPayment.setPayment(newPayment);
bondPayment.setBond(bond);
bond.setBondPayment(bondPayment);
```

In the first case, the `BondPayment.id` is kept, and you are just changing the `payment` for it. In the second case, it's a brand new `BondPayment`, and it will conflict with an existing record in the database.

I said that Hibernate is doing the right thing because it threats `BondPayment` as a "regular" entity, whose lifecycle is defined by your app. It's the same as having a `User` with a unique constraint on `login`, and you are trying to insert a second record with a duplicate `login`. Hibernate will accept (it doesn't knows if the `login` exists in the database) and your database will refuse.

Comment: You're right, its `Bond` - 1:M - `BondPayment` - M:1 - `Payment`.

Comment: So, you'll have to deal with it the way I mentioned, which will trigger a select in the BondPayments table and a subsequent update on it.

Comment: Hmmm, fair enough. I'm not sure that the way they're coding the app is going to allow this. I believe it's all automated on the page, and having to do some custom code when a user adds a BondPayment, to search for an older BondPayment that the user just deleted, and change it to an update, sounds like more work than they'd be prepared to do for something that is "just working" as it is :)

Comment: Accepted. We've since made the constraint IMMEDIATE, thus solving the issue, because the developers have modified the frontend to automatically "recycle" existing rows instead of deleting-then-inserting them.